# WebGL iOS render to floating point texture

Tags: javascript, ios, opengl-es, webgl

I'm trying to get rendering to a floating point texture working in WebGL on iOS Safari (not in a native app). I have managed to get iOS to read a manually (e.g. from JavaScript) created floating point texture, however when I create a framebuffer of floating point type and use the GPU to render into it, it does not work.

I've isolated the issue to code that renders to a floating point texture, which is then passed to another shader to be displayed. Here is what the result looks like applied to a cube:

[image]

The render to texture draws a green square, half the size of the texture, which is then applied to each side of the cube.

This all works perfectly fine on both desktop and iOS WebGL as long as the type of the texture that the green square is rendered to is the standard unsigned byte type. However, changing the type to floating point causes the render to texture to fail on iOS devices (while continuing to work on desktop browsers). The texture is empty, as if nothing had been rendered to it.

I have created an example project here to demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/felixpalmer/render-2-texture

Changing the precision of the shaders using the `THREE.Renderer.precision` setting does not make a difference

Comment: Till fp textures are supported, if you have access to the full sources, you can try changing the texture write to regular non-float textures, and convert to float when you read back inside the next shader,

Comment: Yes, but I lose precision. So If I have 4 floating point channels and switch to bytes, I cannot send 32 bits in each channel, so I'd need to pack them floats , which would mean using more textures. Not great, but that is my current plan B.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I know no iOS device supports rendering to a floating point texture (nor do most mobile devices at this point in time 3/2015)

My understanding of the WebGL spec is

`OES_texture_float`: Allows you to create and read from 32bit float textures but rendering to a floating point is device dependent.

`OES_texture_float_linear`: Allows linear filter floating point textures. If this doesn't exist and `OES_texture_float` does then you can only use `gl.NEAREST` for floating point textures.

`OES_texture_half_float` and `OES_texture_half_float_linear` are the same as above except for half float textures.

The traditional way to see if you can render to a floating point texture in WebGL, assuming `OES_texture_float` exists, is to create a framebuffer, attach a floating point texture to it, then call `gl.checkFramebufferStatus`. If it returns `gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE` then you can, if not then you can't. Note: This method should work regardless of the next paragraph.

The spec was updated so you could also check WebGL extensions to find out if it's possible to render to a floating point texture. The extension `WEBGL_color_buffer_float` is supposed to tell you you can render to floating point textures. The extension `EXT_color_buffer_half_float` is the same for half float textures. I know of no browser that actually shows these extensions though yet they support floating point rendering if the hardware supports it.

For example my 2012 Retina MBP on Chrome 41 reports

```
gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl").getSupportedExtensions()
["ANGLE_instanced_arrays", 
 "EXT_blend_minmax", 
 "EXT_frag_depth",  
 "EXT_shader_texture_lod",  
 "EXT_sRGB",  
 "EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic",  
 "WEBKIT_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic",  
 "OES_element_index_uint",  
 "OES_standard_derivatives",  
 "OES_texture_float",  
 "OES_texture_float_linear",  
 "OES_texture_half_float",  
 "OES_texture_half_float_linear",  
 "OES_vertex_array_object",  
 "WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc",  
 "WEBKIT_WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc",  
 "WEBGL_debug_renderer_info",  
 "WEBGL_debug_shaders",  
 "WEBGL_depth_texture",  
 "WEBKIT_WEBGL_depth_texture",  
 "WEBGL_lose_context",  
 "WEBKIT_WEBGL_lose_context"]
```

Firefox 36 reports

```
gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl").getSupportedExtensions().join("\n")
"ANGLE_instanced_arrays
EXT_blend_minmax
EXT_frag_depth
EXT_sRGB
EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
OES_element_index_uint
OES_standard_derivatives
OES_texture_float
OES_texture_float_linear
OES_texture_half_float
OES_texture_half_float_linear
OES_vertex_array_object
WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc
WEBGL_depth_texture
WEBGL_draw_buffers
WEBGL_lose_context
MOZ_WEBGL_lose_context
MOZ_WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc
MOZ_WEBGL_depth_texture"
```

The browser vendors are busy implementing WebGL 2.0 and given the `gl.checkFramebufferStatus` method works there's no pressure to spend time making the other extension strings appear.

Apparently some iOS devices support `EXT_color_buffer_half_float` so you could try creating a half float texture, attach it to a framebuffer and check its status then see if that works.

Here's a sample to check support. Running it on my iPadAir2 and my iPhone5s I get

```
can make floating point textures
can linear filter floating point textures
can make half floating point textures
can linear filter floating point textures
can **NOT** render to FLOAT texture
successfully rendered to HALF_FLOAT_OES texture
```

which is exactly what we expected.

```js
"use strict";

function log(msg) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}                  

function glEnum(gl, v) {
  for (var key in gl) {
    if (gl[key] === v) {
      return key;
    }
  }
  return "0x" + v.toString(16);
}

window.onload = function() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  var canvas = document.getElementById("c");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if (!gl) {
    return;
  }
  
  
  function getExt(name, msg) {
    var ext = gl.getExtension(name);
    log((ext ? "can " : "can **NOT** ") + msg);
    return ext;
  }
  
  var testFloat = getExt("OES_texture_float", "make floating point textures");
  getExt("OES_texture_float_linear", "linear filter floating point textures");
  var testHalfFloat = getExt("OES_texture_half_float", "make half floating point textures");
  getExt("OES_texture_half_float_linear", "linear filter half floating point textures");
  
  gl.HALF_FLOAT_OES = 0x8D61;
  
  // setup GLSL program
  var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["2d-vertex-shader", "2d-fragment-shader"]);
  gl.useProgram(program);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "a_position"); 
  var colorLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_color");

  // provide texture coordinates for the rectangle.
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
     -1.0, -1.0,
      1.0, -1.0,
     -1.0,  1.0,
     -1.0,  1.0,
      1.0, -1.0,
      1.0,  1.0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
  
  var whiteTex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, whiteTex);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                new Uint8Array([255, 255, 255, 255]));
  
  function test(format) {
    var tex = gl.createTexture();
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 1, 1, 0, gl.RGBA, format, null);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
    
    var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);
    gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
    var status = gl.checkFramebufferStatus(gl.FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (status !== gl.FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
      log("can **NOT** render to " + glEnum(gl, format) + " texture");
      return;
    }
    
    // Draw the rectangle.
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, whiteTex);
    gl.uniform4fv(colorLoc, [0, 10, 20, 1]);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    
    
    gl.clearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    gl.uniform4fv(colorLoc, [0, 1/10, 1/20, 1]);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    
    var pixel = new Uint8Array(4);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
    
    if (pixel[0] !== 0 ||
        pixel[1] < 248 ||
        pixel[2] < 248 ||
        pixel[3] < 254) {
      log("FAIL!!!: Was not able to actually render to " + glEnum(gl, format) + " texture");
    } else {
      log("succesfully rendered to " + glEnum(gl, format) + " texture");
    }    
  }
  if (testFloat) {
    test(gl.FLOAT);
  }
  if (testHalfFloat) {
    test(gl.HALF_FLOAT_OES);
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="16" height="16"></canvas>  
<!-- vertex shader -->
<script id="2d-vertex-shader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
attribute vec4 a_position;

void main() {
   gl_Position = a_position;
}
</script>
<!-- fragment shader -->
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
precision mediump float;
uniform vec4 u_color;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;

void main() {
   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, vec2(0.5, 0.5)) * u_color;
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is great, thank you for taking the time. I figured it wasn't supported, but nice to have it confirmed. Also, the HALF_FLOAT support is a surprise, and basically solves my issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Great answer.  Also, the object returned [gl.getExtension("OES_texture_half_float")](http://www.javascripture.com/WebGLRenderingContext#getExtension) has the value of HALF_FLOAT_OES on it so you don't need to hard code it.

Comment: Surprisingly it's considered best practice to hard code WebGL constants. I don't usually do it since I'm not trying to mega optimize but looking the constants up on the `WebGLRenderingContext` is much slower than making them `const` or `var` variables because coming off an object they have to be searched for at every access as they might have changed. Variables would have no search and any good minifier/optimizer will change them all to not use the variables at all making them as fast as possible. I suppose an optimizer could optionally do that for WebGL by replacing `gl.CONST` with the value.